# How to use base R to write table to .xlsx?

Tags: r

Apologies but I'm new to R. I'm able to write a data table to a .csv and a .txt file but I'd like to write it to an .xlsx file. Is this possible using base R?
Thanks

Comment: Try the [readxl](http://readxl.tidyverse.org/index.html) package for a solution that doesn't need a java install.

Comment: `readxl` does **not** allow you to write to xlsx. See here for a discussion on [GitHub](https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/231). You could use [writexl](https://github.com/ropensci/writexl).

Comment: Another alternative is the package `openxlsx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For doing this you need to have xlsx package installed.
The you can try.

```
library(xlsx)
xlsx.writeMultipleData <- function (file, ...)
  {
    require(xlsx, quietly = TRUE)
    objects <- list(...)
    fargs <- as.list(match.call(expand.dots = TRUE))
    objnames <- as.character(fargs)[-c(1, 2)]
    nobjects <- length(objects)
    for (i in 1:nobjects) {
        if (i == 1)
            write.xlsx(objects[[i]], file, sheetName = objnames[i])
        else write.xlsx(objects[[i]], file, sheetName = objnames[i],
            append = TRUE)
    }
  }
```

Comment: The OP is new to R. You should probably illustrate what using this function would look like.

Answer (score 2):

The writexl package is quite nice. No 'Java' or 'Excel' required.

`library(writexl)
write_xlsx(df,'filename.xlsx')`